# Network Disconnects with Killer AC-1525 card

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I am using a Killer Wireless Networks AC-1525 but I am having constant problems with it, including sudden disconnects and poor WiFi signal, even though I have updated my firmware and installed the recommended patches according to the Killer Networks [post](https://www.killernetworking.com/killersupport/driver-downloads/kb/faq/80-wi-fi-disconnects-and-latency-on-debian-ubuntu-and-arch-3). Any other hint how I can fix my issues or the only solution is to buy another M2 WiFi card with a better Linux driver support?
That's the output of `lshw`:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 20
       serial: 74:29:af:33:3d:4f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-44-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.178.95 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:35 memory:d1400000-d15fffff
```

And the output of dmesg because I just had a disconnect:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    4.719577] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x200 build 0x299, firmware rome 0x200 build 0x111
[    5.025720] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:07:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    5.025728] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:07:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    5.026034] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-6.bin failed with error -2
[    5.027514] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
[  313.893273] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid 15278f33-b13c-45fa-976c-342587a4ac4f)
[  313.893701] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
[  313.895944] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware register dump:
```